# Mysql - How to select users who have similar info (like a shared phone number)

Tags: mysql

Just for an example. How can I query my db to find two users who might be using the same phone number? I'm not inputting a specific number but I want to find all instances phone numbers that are being used more than once in the user table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT ... FROM users u1 JOIN users u2 
ON u1.user_id <> u2.user_id AND u1.phone_number = u2.phone_number;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use two tables of the same table with aliasses like:

```
select a.name, b.name
  from mytable a join mytable b on a.phonenumber = b.phonenumber
 where a.name <> b.name
```